# Is whether sharing the secondary storage one difference between clusters and grids?

Tags: grid, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, cpu-architecture

Is whether sharing the secondary storage one difference between clusters and grids?

I.e.

In a cluster, do all the computers share the disks so the cpus see a single distributed file system?

In a grid, do all the computers not share the disks, so the cpus don't see each other's disk and file system?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the concept of storage is the main point of difference between cluster systems and grid systems. ([The below explanation is copied from "Comparison of Grid Computing vs. Cluster Computing"](http://www.jatit.org/research/introduction_grid_computing.htm))

Grid systems are loosely coupled(decentralised), whereas cluster systems are tightly coupled.

Grid systems have "distributed job management and scheduling policies", whereas cluster systems are "centralized job management & scheduling system".

> 1. The big difference is that a cluster is homogenous while grids are heterogeneous.

The computers that are part of a grid can run different operating systems and have different hardware whereas the cluster computers all have the same hardware and OS. A grid can make use of spare computing power on a desktop computer while the machines in a cluster are dedicated to work as a single unit and nothing else. *Grid are inherently distributed by its nature over a LAN, metropolitan or WAN*. On the other hand, *the computers in the cluster are normally contained in a single location or complex*.

> 2. Another difference lies in the way resources are handled.

In case of Cluster, the whole system (all nodes) behave like a single system view and resources are managed by centralized resource manager. In case of Grid, every node is autonomous i.e. it has its own resource manager and behaves like an independent entity.

> Question - Is whether sharing the secondary storage one difference between
>   clusters and grids?

As [Wikipedia page on Computer cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) states :-

*"In most circumstances, all of the nodes use the same hardware[2] and the same operating system, although in some setups (i.e. using Open Source Cluster Application Resources (OSCAR)), different operating systems can be used on each computer, and/or different hardware."*

Comment: Thanks. Can you address my secondary storage (hard disk) question?

Comment: @Tim - Yes, I've edited that art in my answer. Check my edit in the answer. BTW, generally(almost) it is the same secondary storage(hardware).

Comment: My question is: are clusters and grids different in whether the computers share secondary storage (i.e. their hard disks)?

Comment: @Tim - Computers don't share their hard disks in GRID systems; their jobs are independent of one other and so they have different hard disks OR/AND OS. I have already made the necessary edit. You seem to not revisit the answer. Please revisit the answer and feel free to ask any doubt.

Comment: @Tim - The answer hasn't been accepted still, please accept the answer. See how to accept an answer ---> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work